# Slide animation in Xamarin forms

Tags: animation, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to animate a StackLayout. Two requirements:

1. The stack layout moves horizontally and comes back to its original position.  It should animate in such a manner that it feels like it disappears from the right side of the screen and appears from the left.
2. When half of the stack layout goes out of the right side, the other half should be visible on the left side of the screen i.e. Translate around the screen

I wrote this:

```
await sl.TranslateTo(800, 0, 0);
await sl.TranslateTo(0,0,1000);
```

It satisfies the requirement 1 but I am not able to figure out a solution to #2.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Flexlayout
[FlexLayout Demos](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/FlexLayoutDemos/)
Almost Exactly what you requested except that it doesn't go back to the first part when you reach the end.

You might need to create a condition and play with some events.
good luck

Comment: The problem is, I am using v 2.5

Comment: You are bound to update Xamarin forms for getting new features or to patch issues. You can test the waters if you are using a versioning system like github or bitbucket. Update Xamarin forms and see if everything is working as expected. otherwise, revert the changes.